# How does this R code work?

Tags: r

I had a task in R-classes: create a variable good_months and add to it only those values from AirPassengers, which are greater than previous one. I completed this task with for-loop:

```
good_months <- NA
month <- as.vector(AirPassengers)

i = 1
for(i in i:(length(month)-1)){
  if(month[i+1] > month[i]){
    good_months[i] <- month[i+1]
    i =+ 1} else {i =+ 1}
}
```

But I was told that this task can be completed in this way:

```
good_months <- AirPassengers[-1][AirPassengers[-1] > AirPassengers[-144]]
```

This code makes the same and does it simpler, but I don't understand how it works. Can you explain?

Comment: Simpler still `AirPassengers[c(FALSE,diff(AirPassengers) > 0)]`. Try running the code piece by piece to understand the whole.

Comment: FWIW you _almost never_ want to do that piecemeal vector building with a `for` loop in R. It gets very slow very quickly :-) One of the most difficult thing for folks starting out with R to deal with (esp if they come from purely procedural languages or bastardized list-ified languages like python) is the concept of vectorized operations. You need to let R rewrite your neurons to fully appreciate the power of vectorized ops.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is it?

```
class(AirPassengers)
## [1] "ts"
```

Take a look at it:

```
AirPassengers
##      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
## 1949 112 118 132 129 121 135 148 148 136 119 104 118
## 1950 115 126 141 135 125 149 170 170 158 133 114 140
## 1951 145 150 178 163 172 178 199 199 184 162 146 166
## 1952 171 180 193 181 183 218 230 242 209 191 172 194
## 1953 196 196 236 235 229 243 264 272 237 211 180 201
## 1954 204 188 235 227 234 264 302 293 259 229 203 229
## 1955 242 233 267 269 270 315 364 347 312 274 237 278
## 1956 284 277 317 313 318 374 413 405 355 306 271 306
## 1957 315 301 356 348 355 422 465 467 404 347 305 336
## 1958 340 318 362 348 363 435 491 505 404 359 310 337
## 1959 360 342 406 396 420 472 548 559 463 407 362 405
## 1960 417 391 419 461 472 535 622 606 508 461 390 432
```

Indexing it in this way changes the behaviour of the object:

```
AirPassengers[-1]
##   [1] 118 132 129 121 135 148 148 136 119 104 118 115 126 141 135 125 149
##  [18] 170 170 158 133 114 140 145 150 178 163 172 178 199 199 184 162 146
##  [35] 166 171 180 193 181 183 218 230 242 209 191 172 194 196 196 236 235
##  [52] 229 243 264 272 237 211 180 201 204 188 235 227 234 264 302 293 259
##  [69] 229 203 229 242 233 267 269 270 315 364 347 312 274 237 278 284 277
##  [86] 317 313 318 374 413 405 355 306 271 306 315 301 356 348 355 422 465
## [103] 467 404 347 305 336 340 318 362 348 363 435 491 505 404 359 310 337
## [120] 360 342 406 396 420 472 548 559 463 407 362 405 417 391 419 461 472
## [137] 535 622 606 508 461 390 432

class(AirPassengers[-1])
## [1] "numeric"
```

As you can see, it made the time series a numeric vector and removed the first element:

```
length(AirPassengers)
## [1] 144
```

This removes the last element:

```
AirPassengers[-144]
##   [1] 112 118 132 129 121 135 148 148 136 119 104 118 115 126 141 135 125
##  [18] 149 170 170 158 133 114 140 145 150 178 163 172 178 199 199 184 162
##  [35] 146 166 171 180 193 181 183 218 230 242 209 191 172 194 196 196 236
##  [52] 235 229 243 264 272 237 211 180 201 204 188 235 227 234 264 302 293
##  [69] 259 229 203 229 242 233 267 269 270 315 364 347 312 274 237 278 284
##  [86] 277 317 313 318 374 413 405 355 306 271 306 315 301 356 348 355 422
## [103] 465 467 404 347 305 336 340 318 362 348 363 435 491 505 404 359 310
## [120] 337 360 342 406 396 420 472 548 559 463 407 362 405 417 391 419 461
## [137] 472 535 622 606 508 461 390
```

R logical operators are vectorized, so

```
AirPassengers[-1] > AirPassengers[-144]
##   [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
##  [12] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##  [23]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##  [34] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
##  [45] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##  [56] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##  [67] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##  [78]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
##  [89]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
## [100]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
## [111] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
## [122]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
## [133] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

creates a logical vector comparing each pair to each other.

```
AirPassengers[-1][AirPassengers[-1] > AirPassengers[-144]]
##  [1] 118 132 135 148 118 126 141 149 170 140 145 150 178 172 178 199 166
## [18] 171 180 193 183 218 230 242 194 196 236 243 264 272 201 204 235 234
## [35] 264 302 229 242 267 269 270 315 364 278 284 317 318 374 413 306 315
## [52] 356 355 422 465 467 336 340 362 363 435 491 505 337 360 406 420 472
## [69] 548 559 405 417 419 461 472 535 622 432
```

That creates a numeric vector of the time series without the first element and uses the fact that you can logically include/exclude vector components.